# How write a tweet using TwitterOAuth PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm tring to write a tweet, with my app twitter, using `twitterOAuth`.
My code works to write the tweet but there's an error (i don't know where) that breaks my code.
Maybe i use a old version of **twitterOAuth**

```
My code is this:

// OAuth To Twitter
require_once 'files-notifiche-twitter/twitteroauth.php';

// Do NOT Share (sono i token)
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "xxx");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "xxx");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "xxx");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "xxx");

// Post To Twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'tweet'));


if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() != 200) {    
    print_r('<br>Error try again<br>');     
} 
else{
   print_r('<br>Notifica twitter funziona<br>');
}

print_r('OK');
```

Code write the tweet but not `print_r` inside **if statment** and last **print_r('OK');

Can you say me if this code is correct?
And where i can download a correct version of `twitterOAuth` ?

In my file of `twitterOAuth` there's

```
 require_once('OAuth.php');
```

Maybe is `'OAuth.php'` is old...

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: Twitter itself has a list of libraries that work with Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries Maybe choose one of those if you want to switch.

Comment: i don't understand if the file is only this https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/TwitterOAuth.php

Comment: I doubt there's one file out of date. Abrahams site is https://twitteroauth.com/ which has some examples of how to do stuff. See if that helps.